# CSS Advanced Three Button Row Formatting

Tags: html, css, button, ionic2, styles

I am trying to style a row of buttons in the Ionic 2 framework and am having some trouble.

This is what the buttons I currently have look like:

[image]

What I would like them to look like is something more along the lines of the following image:

[image]

I would like the end result to have a larger circular button in the middle, with the two buttons on each of its side having a border that goes along with the curvature of the center button.

I am new to styling and do not really know where to start with this, so any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the CSS so far that I have added to my buttons.

```css
.button-row-icons {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.left-right-buttons {
  background: none;
  color: #AD001A;
  border: 2px solid #AD001A;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.left-right-buttons:active {
  background: #eee;
}

#select-button {
  border-radius: 40%;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

#left-button {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

#right-button {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
                    <ion-row class="button-row">
                        <ion-col col-5 class="button-col">
                            <button class="left-right-buttons" id="left-button" ion-button no-shadow (click)="swipeCard(false)">
                                <ion-icon class="button-row-icons" name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon>
                            </button>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col col-2 class="button-col">
                            <button id="select-button" ion-button no-shadow (click)="selectCard(restaurant)">
                                <ion-icon class="button-row-icons" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
                            </button>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col col-5 class="button-col">
                            <button class="left-right-buttons" id="right-button" ion-button no-shadow (click)="swipeCard(true)">
                                <ion-icon class="button-row-icons" name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
                            </button>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
```

Comment: Please add HTML as well.

Comment: @SauravRastogi Added the relevant HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS Flexbox, `margin` and `z-index`  to arrange elements. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.button-row-icons {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  display: flex;
}

.left-right-buttons {
  background: none;
  color: #AD001A;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 2px solid #AD001A;
  margin: 0px !important;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.left-right-buttons:active {
  background: #eee;
}

#select-button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px !important;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

#left-button {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  margin: 5px -20px 0 0 !important;
}

#right-button {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 -20px !important;
}
```

```html
<ion-row class="button-row">
    <ion-col col-5 class="button-col">
        <button class="left-right-buttons" id="left-button" ion-button no-shadow (click)="swipeCard(false)">
            <ion-icon class="button-row-icons" name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon> L
        </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-2 class="button-col">
        <button id="select-button" ion-button no-shadow (click)="selectCard(restaurant)">
            <ion-icon class="button-row-icons" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon> M
        </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-5 class="button-col">
        <button class="left-right-buttons" id="right-button" ion-button no-shadow (click)="swipeCard(true)">
            <ion-icon class="button-row-icons" name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon> R
        </button>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Hope this helps and is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a huge step in the right direction

Comment: @biggytiny It's my pleasure.